# Hartman-Grobman Theorem - Necessary?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-topology, dynamical-systems, control-theory, nonlinear-system

The Hartman-Grobman theorem states, in layman's terms, that a nonlinear system and the corresponding liniarized system behave similarly around a hyperbolic equilibrium point (in terms of vector fields that dictate the evolution of states).

But is this theorem necessary for this to be true? Can a linearized system with a single eigenvalue on the imaginary axis not behave like its nonlinear counterpart?

I would request any specific references to the given answers so that I can read it and verify by myself!

Comment: Examples are the answer to your question. Let's start from canonical one. Can you sketch the phase portrait for $\dot{x} = x^2, \, \dot{y} = -y$ and compare it with linearization?

Answer (score 0):

As @Evgeny commented, the system $\dot x = x^2$ is one of the simplest examples. The situation is analogical to trying to determine whether a local extremum of a function is maximum or minimum when the second derivative is zero: E.g. $x^3$ and $x^4$ have booth first and second derivative zero at $x=0$, but only the later has local minimum at the point.

I recommend the book by [Phase Portraits of Planar Quadratic Systems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387304134) 2007 by John Reyn to see endless examples demonstrating why the condition that the real part of each of the eigenvalues is nonzero is essential.